# Allow opening my app from a link in a third-party app

Tags: ios, url-scheme

I'm currently using a custom URL scheme to allow users to access my app (say, `FoobarApp`) from custom links (`foobar://resource/42`).

I set up the scheme like so :

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>com.acme.foobarapp</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>foobar</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

This works well when the users click the link in Safari.

Now I'd like them to be able to click said links in third-party apps (in my case Trello), to open my app.

This does not work, as the system (since iOS 9 if I'm not mistaken) now requires that apps whitelist URL scheme they want to query (with the `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` in Info.plist).

(This is the message I get in the logs when I click the link in the third-party app:

> iPad Trello(UIKit)[2368] : -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "foobar://resource/42" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme foobar"

)

It's not reasonable to expect the third-party app to add my (enterprise) app's scheme to their `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` list. Is their any option to "bypass" this protection? A kind of way to tell the system "It's fine, Trello can open my app"?

### Summary

- Custom app links `foobar://` work in Safari
- They don't work in third-party app (nothing happens, see log a few lines up)
- How can I whitelist third-party apps so they can open *my* app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an app has to tell ios it wants to query a url scheme. It has to declare this in its info plist at compile time!

## There is no way around this on a apple allowed iPhone.

Sure when you jailbreak a phone, all can be done but... thats not a valid assumption either ;)

---

a workaround may be to link to a Website via HTTP and have the user open the app from there.

Comment: Also only `canOpenUrl` is restricted by the `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes `, [`openURL:`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplication/1622961-openurl). So if an app is just opening your URL it should work.

Comment: very true. I focused on canOpen since the OP showed the error from trello. I forgot this

Comment: Thanks @Daij-Djan. We ended up using your workaround, a HTTP link with our server returning a 301 redirect to the `foobar://` scheme